# How to add total average column - postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this table and I want to add another column to calculate the average of the seconds column.
For example:

my table:

| id | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 |
| 2 | 3.2 |
| 3 | 4.1 |
| 4 | 0.8 |

my desired table:

| id | avg | daily_avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 2.65 |
| 2 | 3.2 | 2.65 |
| 3 | 4.1 | 2.65 |
| 4 | 0.8 | 2.65 |

Is there any simple and short way to do it?
Im using postgreSQL

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5ef34b0a68eb4ba5e7e5feb77f5b2ec3)

You can use the `AVG()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    id, avg,
    AVG(avg) OVER () AS daily_avg
FROM mytable
```